# Confusion about a sentence with adjective with "or"

Tags: adjectives

The statement is:

- *You won't need to provide the information of their non-accompanying spouse/partner or dependent children.*

I am trying to understand the real meaning of this sentence. Does the word "non-accompanying" also apply to the dependent children?

Comment: As it stands, I don't think there's enough information in that single sentence to make a judgment either way.

Comment: Here, the intended sense includes children too.

Comment: 'Red socks and shorts' and 'red socks or shorts' are famously ambiguous. This has been covered before, but I've timed myself out on a search.